# UPDATE from subquery updates rows that shouldn't be updated

Tags: postgresql, update, table, where

Using PostgreSQL, I want to update a column. The information how to update is in another table.

My try was this, but it also updates rows I don't want to update:

```
update table_1
set column_x = (
    select table_2.rename
    from table_2    
    where table_2.rename IS NOT NULL 
        and table_1.id = table_2.id)
```

How to modify the query?

Maybe this helps to explain my problem: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/318fb/1

Comment: There is no way that this statement will delete any rows (unless there are triggers involved that do that).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: It would seem the OP actually meant "update the column with NULL" when (s)he wrote "delete".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, I guess you are right.

Comment: i added an sql fiddle link. i hope it helps to understand. i just want to update id 2 and id 5

Comment: Problem in your fiddle: you have alias `t2` for  `table_2` but still reference the original name which is not possible - the mismatch between `table2` and `table_2` aside. And your test needs to consider actual NULL values. I added an extended test case to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `FROM` clause to join to more tables:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1    -- alias optional
SET    column_x = t2.rename
FROM   table_2 t2
WHERE  t2.rename IS NOT NULL  -- assuming you actually meant t1
AND    t2.id = t1.id;
```

This joins rows from `table_2` in a `CROSS JOIN` - filtered by the condition `t2.id = t1.id` which makes it an `INNER JOIN` effectively.

This way, rows without a match in the other table are not touched at all - unlike your query with a correlated subquery.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aea31/5) with extended demo.

You must also understand the difference between NULL, empty string and "no row" (which results in NULL in your correlated subquery).

[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. worked with the following ...

```
UPDATE table1
SET    value = t2.rename
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE  t2.rename IS NOT NULL 
AND    id = t2.id;
```